# ¿Cuál es la etimología de "tío"? ¿Por qué viene de una palabra griega que quiere decir "divino"?

Tags: etimología, latín, parentesco, griego

La palabra *tío* da mucho de sí:

- [¿Se solapan las acepciones 6 y 7 de "tío" en el DLE?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/26596/1674)
- [¿Por qué "tío" designa cariñosamente a una persona próxima?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/22848/1674)
- [Does using "tío" imply a negative opinion?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/468/1674)

En este caso concreto, me estoy fijando en la etimología de la palabra:

> [**tío, a**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=ZoWtFfy)
>   Del lat. tardío *thius*, y este del gr. θεῖος *theîos*.

Si mi griego no me traiciona, y como leo en [Wiktionary por *θεῖος*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%CE%B8%CE%B5%E1%BF%96%CE%BF%CF%82) vendría a tener un sentido de *divino*.

¿En qué punto de la evolución de la palabra se pasó de querer decir *divino* a querer decir *el hermano del padre o de la madre*?

Comment: Yo esa etimología no la veo clara. Puedes mirar esto que escribí hace tiempo, por si te sirve: https://www.delcastellano.com/etimologias-familiares/#etimologia-de-tio-tia

Comment: @Paco caramba! Pues ese trozo de la entrada de tu blog bien podría dar para un inicio de respuesta, explicando la hipótesis de _mamar_. ¿Crees que la parte no clara vendría del paso del griego al latín? Lo mismo los compañeros de [latin.se] nos podrían echar un cable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hay dos palabras θείος en griego antiguo, de distinta raíz.

Una (cognado con *feria, fiesta, feral, fanático, fano, profano*):

> `PIE` [*dʰéh₁s](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Indo-European/d%CA%B0%C3%A9h%E2%82%81s) <sub>("dios")</sub> → *dʰéh₁s-yo- → `PH` *tʰḗhyos → `gr` **θεῖος** <sub>("divino")</sub>

Y otra, de ahí *tío, tía* (cognado con *hembra, heno, hijo, feliz, fémina, feto, felación*):

> `PIE` [*dʰeh₁(y)-](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Indo-European/d%CA%B0eh%E2%82%81(y)-) <sub>("amamantar" / "mamar")</sub> → `gr` **θεῖος** <sub>("tío")</sub> → `lat` thius → `esp` tío

Comment: Interesante. Es gracioso de todos modos que se asocie _amamantar_ con el tío. ¿Será porque la tía según la situación podría estar amamantando a sus sobrinos en caso de pérdida de la madre?

Comment: @fedorqui sí creo que podría tener un origen así, dado que las palabras θηλή (thēlḗ, **“pezón/teta”**), τίτθη (títthē, **“nodriza”**), τήθη (tḗthē, **“abuela”**), θῆλυς (thêlus, **“hembra”**), Τηθύς (Tēthús, **"diosa de fertilidad de agua"**) son también derivadas de *dʰeh₁(y)-.