# ¿Por qué se llama "cubo" si es redondo?

Tags: etimología, sustantivos, ambigüedad

O más bien troncocónico, pero "redondo" es más buscable.
El caso es que esto:

[image]

Se llama "cubo", pero su forma no tiene nada que ver con la de esto:

[image]

Que también se llama "cubo".

Entonces, ¿por qué el primero se llama "cubo" si no tiene forma cúbica?

Comment: Hola walen. Creo que la palabra que buscas es *troncocónico*. https://dle.rae.es/?id=amxGvIw

Comment: ¿Será porque la palabra se estableció antes de la invención del plástico?

Comment: Hay cubos de otros materiales, no solo de plástico

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Hay dos etimologías aquí:

| Palabra | Signifocado | Etimología |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [cubo](https://dle.rae.es/?id=BWd02bp) | recipiente para líquidos | del latín ***cupa*** (via esp. *cuba*) "barrica" |
| [cubo](https://dle.rae.es/?id=BWdCFyL) ◻️ | forma geométrica | del latín ***cubus*** "forma cúbica" |

Comment: Relacionado (dos distintas etimologías → una ortografía): https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/28573/18348